# Multiple entry Tourist Schengen Visa Required?

Tags: schengen-visas, paris

I am travelling to Bogota, Colombia via CDG, Paris Airport via connecting flights from India, and I am an Indian citizen. On my return journey, I am planning to stay for a couple of days in Paris. I had applied for a multiple entry visa but the visa given to me was a single entry one.

Also, I will be having checked in luggage for my journey and the all the below tickets booked are separate.

My itinerary is as follows:

1. From New Delhi(terminal 3) to Paris (Terminal 1) : Qatar Airways
2. Layover of 6 hours and change of terminals at Paris (T1 to T2E)
3. Paris (Terminal 2E) to Bogota, Colombia : Air France

Return Journey:

1. Bogota, Colombia to Paris (Terminal 2E) : Air France
2. Stay in Paris for 3 days
3. Paris (Terminal 1) to New Delhi(terminal 3) : Air India

Please suggest,

1. Will the single entry Type C visa that has been granted work fine? I dont want to be stuck on my return journey if my single entry has already been utilised.
2. What can I do to overcome the problem if the above visa is insufficient?

Thanks in advance.

sg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have separate tickets, then you're out of luck -- a single-entry visa will not allow you to enter the Schengen area *twice*, which you'd need in order to recheck baggage on the way to Colombia.

(It might have been a tactical mistake to ask for a visa with *multiple* entries instead of *two* entries. People often ask for multiple entries "just in case it works", but specifying 2 entries in particular could have made the consular workers look closer at your itinerary to find a reason for that).

Your only options now are:

- Point out the problem to the consulate and hope that their reaction will be "oops, that was a mistake, we'll fix that". Might be a long shot, but it would be silly not to try.
- Reschedule your travel so you either won't pass through Paris on the way out, or can have your baggage checked through.